# Build tools for automating deployment to Azure?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, azure, build-process

Are there any Visual Studio or command-line build tools that target **deploying to Azure**?

My co-founder and I are constantly pushing new bits to both our staging and production servers on Azure, but we also do a lot of work on the localhost Azure sandbox.

Each of these deployments has a different set of **connection strings in web.config** as well as specific settings for domain names, secret GUIDs and what not.

We're using a manual process to **comment and uncomment things in web.config**, but this is fraught with danger and is terribly error prone. Sometimes we get the connection string wrong and then our staging server is pointing to the localhost DB or vice versa.

Are there any tools, plugins, command files, or build processes we can use to make this process less error prone? It's as if in addition to a **Solution Configuration dropdown** with "*Debug*" and "*Retail*" we also had a **Target Deployment dropdown** with entries for "*localhost*", "*Staging Server*", and "*Production Server*".

Answer (score 2):

Since SDK 1.4 there is an option for managing Azure configuration. Read more about it from my [blog post here](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/08/windows-azure-configuration-settings.html).
Specifically for web.config, since .NET 3.5 SP1 there is web.config transformations, which are based on build configuration. You can read more about web.config transofmrations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx).
And if you have a Silverlight application, you can manage the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in a manner like you manage web.config by following [my post here](http://blogs.staykov.net/2011/10/servicereferenceclientconfig-build.html).

Hope all of the provided links will be helpful!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback and the links. We're looking at your links as I write this and will accept your answer if we find something that's even a halfway hack-a-licious solution for our Azure deployment woes!